# Blood Test Results

Tags: discussion, scope, exact-duplicates

Recently, there have been two questions on blood test results.

First of all, I think stating whether numbers "look good" or recognising problems falls under the *diagnosis part*, which we opted is not suitable for this site.

**However, can we mark questions about blood test results as duplicate?** If we only explain the values, then the questions are not individual anymore.